# Вопрос по циклу foreach

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

```
<?php 
$num = 0;
$arrmsg1[0] = 0;
foreach ($arrmsg as $value) {
  $arrmsg1[$num] = $value;
  $num++;
  if ($num == ($Param['page']-1)*5+4) break;
  }
var_dump ($arrmsg1);
?>
```

Вар дамп выводит, что в массиве $arrmsg1 всего один элемент - 0;
Как можно либо прервать foreach без потери данных на энной итерации или перебрать начиная с энного элемента?

**Обновление**

Есть список юзеров с которыми была переписка,

```
$Param1 = "SELECT `from`, `to` FROM `messages` WHERE `to` = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]' OR `from` = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]'";
$Param2 = '/messages/main/page/';
$Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $Param1);
$n[0] = 0;
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
{
    If ($Row['from'] == $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN']) $arrmsg[$n] = $Row['to'];
    else $arrmsg[$n] = $Row['from'];
    $n[0]++;
}
$arrmsg = array_unique($arrmsg);
```

Необходимо их вывести по 5 на страницу

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать в общем? Похоже на array_slice

Comment: `SELECT distinct if (to = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]', from, to) as user FROM messages WHERE to = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]' OR from = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]' limit 5 offset 5` и стандартная пагинация.

Comment: Этот код надо переварить,я его не совсем понимаю)
что значит if (to = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]', from, to)

Comment: Все, понял if to = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]' THEN from else to

Comment: @Мелкий Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будет разумнее не вычитывать все данные на приложение и там аггрегировать, а посчитать список собеседников сразу на СУБД запросом:

```
SELECT distinct if (to = :user_login, from, to) as user 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE to = :user_login OR from = :user_login 
    limit 5 offset 5
```

И сразу в запросе можно делать разбивку на страницы.

В комментариях не упомянул, т.к. было видно по использованию `mysqli_query` - конструкция `if ( condition, then, else)` из диалекта `mysql` и имеется не во всех СУБД. Для соответствия стандартному `SQL` можно переписать в case

```
SELECT distinct case 
        when to = :user_login then from
        else to
    end as user 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE to = :user_login OR from = :user_login
```

Посчитать на СУБД всё равно производительнее, чем вычитывать таблицу в том же объёме, передавать и аггрегировать на приложении, но на больших объёмах переписок конкретного пользователя (даже если переписывается всего с парой человек, но крайне интенсивно) может давать проблемы - выполнение `distinct` по вычисляемому полю операция не самая дешёвая и индексами не покрывается. Можно будет поизвращаться разными методами, но чаще делают отдельную аггрегированную таблицу диалогов: кто с кем говорил, когда, указатель на последнее сообщение - это все можно получить вычитывая таблицу сообщений, но не всегда оптимально.

Comment: Сработало) ну пока так пусть работает,  про второй метод пока не понятно.)